# Is this XML valid, and how to create it with TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

Is this XML "valid"?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p class="leaders">
    Todd
    <span class="leader-type">.</span>
    R
    <span class="leader-type">.</span>
    Colas
</p>
```

I've never seen an XML doc with multiple "values" for a node like this does for the `<p>` node.

How do I parse out the three values for `<p>` with TXMLDocument?  And how to traverse to the `<span>` nodes?

Finally...how do I create an XML document like this with TXMLDocument????

Help!!!!

Comment: Yes that is perfectly valid XML. It looks like XHTML. Look at it as if it were an HTML document.

Comment: That said, the root node is `<p>` so it's not valid XHTML.

Answer (score 6):

When you say, is it valid, I think you mean: is it well-formed? (We can't tell whether it is valid without a DTD or schema).

Yes, it is well-formed. It is a perfecly normal example of a document containing mixed content, which is what XML is designed for.

I can't answer your questions about TXMLDocument because I've never heard of it: presumably it's part of a delphi XML library.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between well-formed and valid.

Comment: +1 for "well-formed". `TXMLDocument` is a wrapper for the `XML DOM`. By default on the Windows OS, it uses `MS XML` by default; on other OSs (or optionally, if that's your preference), it uses Open Source XML (Xerces or OpenXML depending on the Delphi version, IIRC, but I don't use them so I'm not sure).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is valid XML.  To parse it, you have to understand that XML is represented as a tree of nodes.  That XML would parse into the following tree structure.

```
p
|_ attributes
| |_ "class"="leaders"
|
|_ children
  |_ #text "Todd"
  |
  |_ span
  | |_ attributes
  | | |_ "class"="leader-type"
  | |
  | |_ children
  |   |_ #text "."
  |
  |_ #text "R"
  |
  |_ span
  | |_ attributes
  | | |_ "class"="leader-type"
  | |
  | |_ children
  |   |_ #text "."
  |
  |_ #text "Colas"
```

Each attribute and child node is represents as a separate `IXMLNode` interface in the `TXMLDocument`.  As you can see, the plain text portions are separated into their own `#text` nodes.

Once you have loaded the XML into `TXMLDocument`, the `TXMLDocument.DocumentElement` property represents the `<p>` node.  That node's `AttributeNodes` property contains a "class" node, and its `ChildNodes` property contains the first level of `#text` and `<span>` nodes.  The `<span>` nodes have their own `AttributeNodes` and `ChildNodes` lists, and so on.  So to parse this, you would iterate through the tree looking for the `#text` nodes, using the `<span>` nodes to manipulate the text as needed.

To create such a document, you simply create the individual nodes as needed, eg:

```
Doc.Active := False;
Doc.Active := True;

Node := Doc.AddChild('p');
Node.Attributes['class'] := 'leaders';

Child := Doc.CreateNode('Todd', ntText);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Child);

Child := Node.AddChild('span');
Child.Attributes['class'] := 'leader-type';
Child.Text := '.';

Child := Doc.CreateNode('R', ntText);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Child);

Child := Node.AddChild('span');
Child.Attributes['class'] := 'leader-type';
Child.Text := '.';

Child := Doc.CreateNode('Colas', ntText);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Child);

Doc.SaveTo...(...); // generate the XML to your preferred output
```

If you want whitespace/linebreaks to appear in the XML output, simply include those characters in the content of the `#text` nodes.  When parsing XML into `TXMLDocument`, unnecessary whitespace is stripped off by default. If you want to preserve it, enable the `poPreserveWhiteSpace` flag in the `ParseOptions` property before loading the XML.

Comment: and to view the tree it would be probably most simple to open such XML in web browser. Then use built-in DOM Inspection tools. In MSIE9 that is F12 key, in Chrome r-click and "Inspect" menu, in Opera both ways work.